# How to animate a plot in python using the VisVis package?

Tags: python, animation, plot, visualization

I am trying to animate a plot using visvis.

This is the example code they have:

```
import visvis as vv

# read image
ims = [vv.imread('astronaut.png')]

# make list of images: decrease red channel in subsequent images
for i in range(9):
    im = ims[i].copy()
    im[:,:,0] = im[:,:,0]*0.9
    ims.append(im)

# create figure, axes, and data container object
a = vv.gca()
m = vv.MotionDataContainer(a)

# create textures, loading them into opengl memory, and insert into container.
for im in ims:
    t = vv.imshow(im)
    t.parent = m
```

and I added:

```
app = vv.use()
app.Run()
```

This worked. But I needed to animate a plot, not an image, so I tried doing this:

```
import visvis as vv
from visvis.functions import getframe

# create figure, axes, and data container object
a = vv.gca()
m = vv.MotionDataContainer(a, interval=100)

for i in range(3):
    vv.plot([0, 2+i*10], [0, 2+i*10])
    f = getframe(a)
    t = vv.imshow(f)
    t.parent = m

a.SetLimits(rangeX=[-2, 25], rangeY=[-2, 25])
app = vv.use()
app.Run()
```

The axes are being initialized very big, that is why I am using set limits, and the output is not animated. I am getting only the last frame so a line from (0,0) to (22, 22).

Does anyone know a way of doing this **with visvis**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out adding the frame as a child of `MotionDataContainer` was not the way to go. The function `vv.plot` returns an instance of the class Line, and one should add the line as a child. If anyone is having the same problem, I could write a more detailed answer.

**EDIT** Adding a more detailed answer as requested:

To animate a plot made of lines, one must simply add the lines as children of `MotionDataContainer`. Taking my example in the question above, one would write:

```
import visvis as vv

# create figure, axes, and data container object
a = vv.gca()
m = vv.MotionDataContainer(a, interval=100)

for i in range(3):
    line = vv.plot([0, 2+i*10], [0, 2+i*10]) 
    line.parent = m

app = vv.use()
app.Run()
```

In my special case, I even needed to animate multiple lines being drawn at the same time.
To do this, I ended up defining a new class that, like `MotionDataContainer`, also inherits from `MotionMixin`, and change the class attribute `delta` which specifies how many objects should be made visible at the same time. For that, one has to also rewrite the function `_SetMotionIndex`.

(See visvis official source code: https://github.com/almarklein/visvis/blob/master/wobjects/motion.py)

**Disclaimer:** Concerning the animation of multiple objects, I have no idea if this is the intended use or if this is the easiest solution, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: Please, make sure to detail you answers as much as possible since you can potentially help others in the future. You will see, you will be rewarded accordingly.

Comment: He proposed to improve his answer so I told him to do so...